# AutoHotKey Semantics when using FormatTime

Tags: autohotkey, semantics

I've managed to create a command so when I type "datenow" the current date will be pasted (in international layout) -

```
::datenow::
FormatTime, date,, dd/MM/yyyy {space}
send %date%
return
```

However, everything I know about AutoHotKey would tell me to format the code like this -

```
::datenow::
FormatTime, date := dd/MM/yyyy . {space}
send %date%
return
```

Could someone explain to me why this doesn't work and why it formatting it with " ,, " does work? The error message states the variable name is illegal.

Really appreciate any help and I am fairly new to using AutoHotKey so I apologise if there is a very simple reason why. Thank you.

Comment: Your second example doesn't work because you're trying to assign a value to the variable named "FormatTime, date".   Everything before the assignment operator `:=`  is a variable name.  You are not allowed to have commas and spaces in a variable name, so that's why you are getting the error message that the variable name is illegal.

Comment: okay, makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a variable in the `FormatTime` command like this `date := dd/MM/yyyy`.

From official docs the format of the command is:

```
FormatTime, OutputVar [, YYYYMMDDHH24MISS, Format]
```

So the `Format` is saved in the `OutputVar`, there is no need for variable assignment.

Just read the documentation, and there are examples in the end of each command that can help you.